# Get Id of product being removed from Product Compare

Tags: product-attribute, compare

I am trying to get the id of the product being removed from the Compare Products list. I have successfullye caught the event `catalog_product_compare_remove_product` but when i try to the the id of the product using `$productId = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();` all I get is a counter that increases with one every time i delete a product from the Compare Products list.

Doing the same when catching the event `catalog_product_compare_add_product` returns the product ID as expected.

So, my question is: What is this counter and how can i get the actual prouduct Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
$productId = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getProductId();
```

In this case the entity passed to the observer is not an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`. It is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Compare_Item`.
When calling `getId` on that you get the increment id of the item to compare from the table `catalog_compare_item`.

Comment: And you should use getProductId(), so it looks like this $product->getProductId();

Comment: btw, how can I know what entity is passed to the observer?

Comment: @slice Look in the code that dispatches the event. Search for `Mage::dispathcEvent('event_name_here'`. Don't close the `)` because some parameters may follow.

Comment: @Marius Ok, will check that out.